# jQuery dropdown menu using slideUp() and slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a top-bar that has a button that opens a dropdown menu on the top bar.
The mechanism works, however I am having some trouble when you make multiple-clicks on the button, that causes the animation to stop and stay in an invalid state.

Here is a fiddle with my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/HLaBb/

```
$("#SensorSelectContent").clearQueue();
$("#SensorSelectContent").stop();

if ($(".SensorSelectOpener").hasClass("open")) {
    $(".SensorSelectOpener").removeClass("open");
    $("#SensorSelectContent").slideUp();
    $(".SensorSelectButtonState").html("▼");
} else {
    $(".SensorSelectOpener").addClass("open");
    $("#SensorSelectContent").slideDown();
    $(".SensorSelectButtonState").html("▲");
}
```

Press on the button "Choose Sensors" a few times really quick to see what I mean.

I found out, that this "bug" seems **not** to appear in jQuery v2+.
However I have a lot of code that uses the old "API" from jQuery and I am not sure if upgrading to a newer version is worth the effort.

My question now is:
Is there a way to fix that "bug" without upgrading to a newer version? Or is there a migration plugin for jQuery 2.x like there was for jQuery 1.9.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is `stop(true,true);`. with passing `true` as first argument `(clearQueue )`  the rest of the animations in the queue are removed and never run.

try this

```
// which are displayed as a plot
function ToogleSensorsDropdown() {
//$("#SensorSelectContent").clearQueue(); //<-- no need to call this..if you add true..
$("#SensorSelectContent").stop(true,true);

if ($(".SensorSelectOpener").hasClass("open")) {
    $(".SensorSelectOpener").removeClass("open");
    $("#SensorSelectContent").slideUp();
    $(".SensorSelectButtonState").html("▼");
} else {
    $(".SensorSelectOpener").addClass("open");
    $("#SensorSelectContent").slideDown();
    $(".SensorSelectButtonState").html("▲");
}
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HLaBb/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this already looks much better. However the effect still isn't perfect smooth. If you switch the library to jQuery 2.x you see that it much smoother. Do you know if it is possible to achieve the same thing in jQUery 1.9.1?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same behavior you see when you take my first fiddle and change jQuery to version 2.x